# cannot show api retrive data with the help async await function in frontend in vue js

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios

My code snippet for retrieving and showing data using API are given below

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  import Axios from "axios";

  var ingridient = ref("");
  var allRecipe = [];
  var allData = [];

  async function getRecipes() {
    var allRecipe = [];
    var recipeApi = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${ingridient.value}&app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_key=MY_API_KEY`;
    var recipes = await Axios.get(recipeApi);
    allData = recipes.data.hits;
    allRecipe = allData.map((a) => a.recipe);
    console.log(allRecipe);
    return allRecipe;
  }
</script>

<template>
  <main class="flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="mt-8">Find Your Recipe</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="getRecipes" class="m-2" action="">
      <input
        class="text-black p-1 m-1"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Ingridient Name"
        v-model="ingridient"
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-3 rounded"
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
    <li v-for="recipe in allRecipe" :key="recipe.id">{{ recipe.label }};</li>
  </main>
</template>
```

In Console Log i get see my retrieved data.

[image: Data Array showed in console log]

Now i cannot access that data and cannot show it in the front end of the app

Comment: Why are you [shadowing](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) `allRecipe` in `getRecipes()`?

Comment: if i remove `allRecipe` from `getRecipes()`  still i cannot get my API data to show in frontend.

Comment: I don't know Vue3's composition API but at a guess I'd say `allRecipe` should be [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) if you intend on updating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @phill and @aro. i made `allRecipe` reactive. As **ref** provides object so to put data on it there need to add `allRecipe.value` for putting retrieve data.

```
<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  import Axios from "axios";

  var ingridient = ref("");
  var allRecipe = ref([]);
  var allData = ref([]);

  async function getRecipes() {
    var recipeApi = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${ingridient.value}&app_id=bbb3e735&app_key=cbaf54fdf80717c6a9ac4a88872cefd7`;
    var recipes = await Axios.get(recipeApi);
    allData.value = recipes.data.hits;
    allRecipe.value = allData.value.map((a) => a.recipe);
    console.log(allRecipe);
    return allRecipe;
  }
  
</script>
```